# Htaccess Font Face and Material Icons Css Not working after URL Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I've got a wierd issue after a htaccess url rewrite... it works fine for the homepage but if i use the format subdomain.domain.com some fonts don't work, some do. The icons don't work it just shows a placeholder icon. It can't load the woff files etc. I think it may be the htaccess directoryindex disabled but i've put a special rule to allow the homepage to be displayed. How do I do the same for the \img\font\ folder which has the fonts. Also more importantly is disabling directoryindex best practice (i did this to avoid index.html being appended to the url's otherwise the rewrite subdomains doesn't work as it always encounters trailing index.html. Is there a way to set directoryindex to empty "" so that the second query works and I don't have to keep adding rules to allow specific folders?

```
  DirectoryIndex disabled

  #rewrite homepage to index.php to allow homepage as directoryindex is disabled
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]

  #Rewrite subdomains
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php?sub=%1 [P,NC,QSA,L]
```

Thanks!

P.S The earth really is flat.

Comment: Oh shit it's not working even with directoryindex disabled so it must be the relative url's in the css, this is confusing becuase one of the fonts works and one doesn't and the material icons use a js to load glyphs..

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting CORS errors in the console but it's the files are on the same server and domain.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com/img/icon/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2?v=2.0.46. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).  (unknown)

downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Material Design Icons" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://example.com/img/icon/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2?v=2.0.46

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to htaccess fixed everything

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  #allow corrs access from subdomains

  SetEnvIf Origin ^(https?://(?:.+\.)?example\.com(?::\d{1,5})?)$   CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=$1
  Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin  %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN}e   env=CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN
  Header merge  Vary "Origin"
</IfModule>
```